# source command not working in Bash on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: bash, django, virtualenv

I am use Ubuntu 17.04 and the following code is not working, although it worked for me in the past.

```
#!/bin/bash

APP=personalBlog

USER=root

cd /opt/src/personalblog/conf/

source /opt/venv/ecomex/bin/activate

uwsgi -c uwsgi.ini
```

The error shown is:

```
/opt/src/personalblog/conf/run.sh: 7: /opt/src/personalblog/conf/run.sh: source: not found
/opt/src/personalblog/conf/run.sh: 8: /opt/src/personalblog/conf/run.sh: uwsgi: not found
```

Comment: do you have read/write permissions for that folder?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution

```
#!/bin/bash

APP=personalBlog

USER=root

. /opt/venv/personal/bin/activate

cd /opt/venv/personal/bin

uwsgi --ini /opt/src/personalblog/conf/uwsgi.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

If `uwsgi` is installed in your virtual environment, you should be able to remove the `source` command and change the `uwsgi` command to:

```
/opt/venv/ecomex/bin/uwsgi -c uwsgi.ini
```

You might then have to update your `uwsgi.ini` file to make sure that the python path is correct.

Comment: Thank i have the solution, #!/bin/bash

APP=personalBlog
USER=root

. /opt/venv/personal/bin/activate
cd /opt/venv/personal/bin
uwsgi --ini /opt/src/personalblog/conf/uwsgi.ini

Comment: Glad you got it to work - my point is that if you use the full path to `uwsgi` and set the Python path in your ini file, you probably don't need to source the `activate` script any more.